# Highlight/add background color to php result

Tags: php

This is the original code

```
<?php echo $shippingDescription ?>
```

This is the code I tried

```
<span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;<?php if($shippingDescription=Free Shipping)echo "color:red"?>"><?php echo $shippingDescription; ?></span>
```

Basically I just want it to add a background color to the text/result if it is Free Shipping

Comment: You should learn PHP syntax. First, if you want to compare a variable with a string, it has to be a value representing a [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). In PHP strings can be single or double quoted. Secondly, `$shippingDescription = <something>` will assing `<something>` as a value of the `$shippingDescription` variable, not compare it. For [comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), use `===`. So it should look something like this: `if($shippingDescription === 'Free Shipping' )`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I see:

1. You need to include quotes around 'Free shipping'
2. You are setting $shippingDescription equal to Free Shipping instead of checking to see if it's equal. Use '==' to compare instead of '='. If you want to match case you can also use '===', but I would guess you don't need to be that specific.

Also, you might consider the ternary operator '?'. Instead of the above you could do:

```
<?= $shippingDescription=='Free Shipping'?'color:red':''; ?>
```

If the statement is true you'll get the value before the ':'. If it's false you'll get the value after the ':' -- In this case a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;<?php if($shippingDescription=="Free Shipping")echo "color:red"?>"><?php echo $shippingDescription; ?></span>
```